# Datasnap method name

Tags: rest, delphi, datasnap, delphi-10-seattle

Is there a way to remove the T type from method name in datasnap?

http://localhost/datasnap/rest/TSales/CustomerLookup/

Id like to change TSales to just Sales but it descends from TComponent and forces the T type

Comment: What is the point of your localhost link?

Comment: No that one wanted something else. This is what i was after http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.datasnap/-xe3-can-you-get-more-control-over-the-m/1097157